# Cannot connect with a standalone SSH Client / Can connect from the browser using the Java SSH Client

Tags: unix, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services

I cant connect with the SSH Client

```
ssh -i ~ key.pem ubuntu or root@ipaddress The authenticity of host can't be established. RSA key fingerprint 
is fingerprint Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I am able to connect through Java with the ip address, location of pem and user ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just asking you whether you want to "trust" the computer that you're connecting to.

It will always show up the first time you SSH to a new server. If you get that in the future *and you have connected there before*, that's when you should be worried.

Comment: One extra little question -- How do you change your picture next to your name?

Answer (score 1):

The openssh commandline utility *always* warns you when it doesn't recognise the computer you're connecting to. This is for security, because if the remote host is a phoney, you can be tricked into giving your login information to it.

Are you sure no one is out to get you? If so, type yes and press Enter. Next time you connect, it won't even ask, unless the remote host changes it address or public key.